# How to get/add/changed allowed server variables of IIS Web Site with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm trying to make a PS script that creates an IIS web page, configures a reverse proxy via URL Rewrite and I'm stuck on how to add allowed server variables via PowerShell.

[image]

Does anyone know how to add these variables via powershell for the IIS website?

Comment: Could you pls post your solution as the answer to end this case so that it can easy to be found and help others. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

FYI adding server variable on server level by powershell:

```
Add-WebConfiguration /system.webServer/rewrite/allowedServerVariables -atIndex 0 -value @{name="RESPONSE_SERVER"}
```

this will add the following configuration in applicationhost.config

```
<system.webServer>
...
    <rewrite>
    ...
        <allowedServerVariables>
            <add name="RESPONSE_SERVER" />
        </allowedServerVariables>
    ...
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 2):

as noted in @matija's answer, you will need to ensure you have the web admin module loaded:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
```

then, building on @lia's answer, you can define a function to add multiple variables in an idempotent fashion like this:

```
function Enable-ReverseProxyHeaderForwarding() {
    $requiredVariables = @("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")
    $existingVariables = Get-WebConfiguration -Filter "/system.webServer/rewrite/allowedServerVariables/add" -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\" | ForEach-Object { $_.name }

    foreach ($variable in $requiredVariables) {
        if (-not ($existingVariables -contains $variable)) {
            Add-WebConfiguration "/system.webServer/rewrite/allowedServerVariables" -value @{name = $variable }
        }
    }
}
```

and then execute the function:

```
Enable-ReverseProxyHeaderForwarding
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I have solved this problem

Step 1. Unlock server configuration section

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe unlock config -section:system.webServer/rewrite/allowedServerVariables
```

Now it's posible to get allowed server variables with

```
import-module WebAdministration

$webSiteName = "your-site-name"
$allowedServerVariables = Get-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/${webSiteName}" -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/allowedServerVariables/add" -Name name

Write-Host $allowedServerVariables.Value
```

Example for adding server variables

```
import-module WebAdministration

$webSiteName = "your-web-site-name"
add-webconfigurationproperty -pspath "iis:\sites\${webSiteName}"  -filter "system.webserver/rewrite/allowedservervariables" -name "." -value @{name='HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING'}
```

UPDATE 2
Better solution without PowerShell is to add allowed server variables globally on IIS web server. So each variable will be automatically inherited from new web site.