# How can I set an allowed server variable in my web.config instead of applicationHost.config?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-10, windows-server-2019

I'm running a non core ASP dotnet app on IIS 10.

I'm configuring rewrite rules for https behind a load balancer per this config: https://www.jamescrowley.net/2014/03/07/ssl-termination-and-secure-cookiesrequiressl-with-asp-net-forms-authentication/

This is the part that confuses me:

> You’ll also need to add HTTPS to the list of allowedServerVariables in
> the applicationHost.config (or through the URL Rewrite config)

```
<rewrite>
    <allowedServerVariables>
        <add name="HTTPS" />
    </allowedServerVariables>
</rewrite>
```

"or through the URL Rewrite config" seems to indicate this can be set in `web.config`.

I don't want to add this variable to the global `applicationHost.config` file I want to set it in my specific applications `web.config`.

Where do I put `<allowedServerVariables>` in `web.config`? I tried putting it under the rewrite rules as in the config snippet but I get an error:

[image]

## Edit

This is not a solution to my actual question, but it appears what I was asking for is impossible.

I wanted to set this in my web.config because all the configuration tooling around IIS is terrible and painful to work with, but here we go. The snippet below is how I was able to script this on the server.

```
// Using try catch to make idempotent
// ErrorAction does not work here
// Despite examples online Get-WebConfigurationProperty nor Get-WebConfiguration were able to check if a variable was already set or not
try {
    C:/Windows/system32/inetsrv/appcmd unlock config -section:system.webServer/rewrite/allowedServerVariables
    Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/allowedServerVariables" -name "." -value @{name='HTTPS'}
}catch{}
```

Comment: Here is a (better) scripted solution to add it to applicationHost.config: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76846888/3375325

Answer (score 0):

Try in your web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>           
            <rules>
                <rule name="RULE_NAME">
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="SOME_NAME" value="{SOME_VALUE}"/>
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Some time ago I got this example from https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples

In your example:

```
    <rule name="HTTPS_AlwaysOn" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
        <match url="*" />
        <serverVariables>
            <set name="HTTPS" value="on" />
        </serverVariables>
        ...
```

Comment: OK this does not work. If I do this I get this error `The server variable "HTTPS" is not allowed to be set. Add the server variable name to the allowed server variable list.`

Comment: Yes, first you need to add to applicationHost.config, and then in your specific web.config file.

Comment: Right thats what I'm asking about. If I can avoid having to add it globally at the server level.

Comment: You only allow to set at server level.  You config at site level.  I have not seen that it can be done otherwise in iis

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I get your idea. You don't want to add it to **applicationHost.config**.

But distributed rewrite rules can only set/overwrite the request headers and server variables that are defined in the allowed list for server variables **allowedServerVariables**.  If a distributed rewrite rule attempts to set any server variable that is not listed in the **allowedServerVariables** collection a runtime error will be generated by URL Rewrite Module. The **allowedServerVariables** collection by default is stored in applicationHost.config

So for it to work, it is required to add it to the **allowedServerVariables** collection. This is specifically noted in the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference#using-inbound-rewrite-rules-to-set-request-headers-and-server-variables.